# Run-time error '450' Using Selection.Find on a Word Doc in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am attempting to select a placeholder on a word document to paste the clipboard (which I've copied an excel table to), but am having a hard time selecting that word before pasting. Getting `Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` on line `With Selection.Find`:

```
ActiveDocument.Content.Select

With Selection.Find '<- Error
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "TablePlaceHolder1"
End With

If Selection.Find.Found = True Then
    Selection.Select
End If

ActiveDocument.Range.Paste
```

I have a ton of experience with Word VBA, but working from Excel into Word (or PowerPoint) I've been running into a flurry of errors.

Comment: Why use `Select`? Why not not just `Set Var = WB.WS.Cells.Find("Search")` and `If Not Var Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: @K.Davis I'm searching through a Word Doc - That line looks like something for searching through an excel worksheet?

Comment: Okay, makes more sense now. Haven't used `.Find` in word so I am unsure of the syntax. My apologies.

Comment: @K.Davis No problem. I haven't used it before either, at least not out of excel. Out of word, plenty of times.

Comment: dont you also need `.Execute Forward:=True `? see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/find-object-word

Comment: If your Word template has placeholder text, why not put a bookmark instead and then use Bookmarks("your bookmark") to refer to the spot?

Comment: @braX Hard to tell, can't get past the initial error line to see what else will trip up...

Comment: @HarassedDad Hey that worked like a charm! Much easier. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: Seems `.Find` would be a function with non-optional parameters that returns the object you want in that `With` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to go ahead and post my solution (after @HarassedDad's advice to use a bookmark instead):

```
With WordApp
    .Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="TablePlaceHolder3"
    .Selection.Paste
End With
```

Much simpler than what I was attempting before.